# Attempting to trick NetLogo into executing a function passed as an argument

Tags: netlogo, higher-order-functions

The following produces a compilation error.

```
to-report call-first/last [first/last a-list]
  report first/last a-list
end
```

`a-list` in the body is highlighted with the error: *Expected command.*

So I tried the following.

```
to-report call-first/last [first/last a-list]
  report first map first/last (list a-list)
end
```

This code compiled(!), but when I attempted to have the observer execute it

```
call-first/last first [1 2 3]
```

`call-first/last` was highlighted with the error message: *CALL-FIRST/LAST expected 2 inputs.*

Any thoughts about an alternative approach?

Thanks.

P.S. The bigger picture is to find a way (if there is one) to write a higher-order function in NetLogo.

UPDATE:

Asking the observer to execute the following works properly!

`call-first-last [[a-list] -> first a-list] [1 2 3]`  ;; => 1

`call-first-last [[a-list] -> last  a-list] [1 2 3]`  ;; => 3

But it sure is a long way around!

Another UPDATE:

Tried

```
to-report call-first-last [first-last a-list]
  report first map (runresult first-last) (list a-list)
end
```

This compiled.

But asking the observer to run `call-first-last "first" [1 2 3]` produced a Runtime Error: *FIRST expected 1 input*

So the question seems to come down to whether there is a way (other than using an anonymous expression as above) to write an expression that returns a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I have all the details correct, but my first thought when I saw what you were trying to do is to use `runresult`. This works:

```
to-report call-first-last [first-last a-list]
  report runresult word first-last a-list
end
```

With (for example): call-first-last "last" [1 2 3]

You would need to add some brackets for both `word` and `runresult` as you do more complicated expressions with more than two terms.

Answer (score 3):

> So the question seems to come down to whether there is a way (other than using an anonymous expression as above) to write an expression that returns a function?

And the answer comes down to... no.

When you tried writing `call-first/last first [1 2 3]`, you were trying to use the "concise syntax" for passing procedures to higher-order procedures: passing the name of the procedure directly instead of passing an expression like `[ xs -> first xs ]`. (You can read a bit about it in [the programming guide](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#anonymous-procedures).)

This syntax works with built-in NetLogo primitives like `map` and `foreach`, but not for user-defined procedures. Without getting too formal, the reason for this is that NetLogo primitives' arguments are typed: NetLogo *knows* that the `map` expects a reporter as its first argument, so it can parse a call like `map first my-list-of-lists` correctly. User-written code is not like that: NetLogo has know idea what the type of the `first/last` argument of your `call-first/last` procedure is supposed to be.

The standard way to deal with this is to bite the bullet and just write something like `call-first-last [xs -> first xs] [1 2 3]`.

If that really bothers you, you can use Jen's solution (though it would be a bit slower).

You could also [write an extension](https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/wiki/Extensions-API). NetLogo extensions allow you to write primitives that behave like native NetLogo procedures, and thus support the concise syntax. It might be worth it if you have a whole set of procedures like this, but otherwise, that's a whole lot of trouble just to save a few characters.

<sup>(Side note: it's up to you, of course, but I would avoid using `/` in NetLogo variable names. The language allows it, yes, but for pretty much anyone looking at your code, it looks a heck of a lot like a division...)</sup>